# Under what conditions is $P(⋃x)⊆x$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recently we were asked to prove $x⊆P(⋃x)$ and consider under what circumstance the converse is true. It seems to me that $P(⋃x)⊆x$ is false, but this is apparently not the case. How would one through element chasing show that there exists a set $x$ such that $x⊆P(⋃x)$ is true?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the reverse inclusion at the end of your last sentence?

Answer (score 2):

$P(⋃x)⊆x$ iff $P(⋃x)=x$ (since we already know that $x⊆P(⋃x)$).

For $P(⋃x)=x$ to be true, $x$ has to be equal to $P(y)$ for some $y$.

Conversely, if $x=P(y)$ then $⋃x=y$, so $x=P(⋃x)$.

Conclusion: $P(⋃x)⊆x$ iff $x=P(y)$ for some $y$.